# Why I'm getting Missing prop error on a new NextJS Application. Working Sandbox

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form

So I'm trying to use this example from the example

[enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reusable-rhf-ts-pt6-lcczw1?file=package.json,src%2Fcomponents%2Fatoms%2Finput.tsx)

When I paste the Input Component inside my newly created Next project I get all kinds of problems and have no idea why.

[image]

Is telling me is missing properties that I already defined. But the problem is that the Codesandbox is working fine. I even outdated the sandbox to React 18 and still no problem

Comment: Hard to tell without you showing a better representation of your code. That image is... Lacking.

Comment: If you paste the code from the sandbox on a new React project you would get the same errors. My  running that on an empty project

Comment: Ohh I thought the example was a working version. Either way, pasting your actual code is recommended in the SO guidelines over pasting an image (or sandbox). However, I understand with frameworks like Next it's a pain using the SO code functionality.

Comment: @Millenial2020, I copied the whole sandbox to another one, I don't have any error (except for ReactDOM.render / react 18) [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-asqka9?file=src%2Fcomponents%2Fatoms%2Finput.tsx)

Comment: @Millenial2020, check your eslint parameters if you have this plugin in your project

Comment: What do you mean by this?

Comment: @Millenial2020 check your eslint or tsconfig file